# Calling a method from another class in Python

Tags: python, class

I have a class called `Rabbits` in my current file (called `rabbits.py`).
In `Rabbits`, I have a method called `carrots()`.

In another file, I have a class called `Whales` (in a file called `whales.py`).
In `Whales` I have a method called `swimming()`.

If I'm trying to print a string in `carrots()` that contains what's returned by `swimming()`; how would I do that?  Would it be `print(str(self.whales.swimming())`?

I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Could you include the code to see exactly how you're creating the instances?

Comment: Why do you think that calling another class's method on your class would be a sensible thing to do?

Comment: "what's returned by swimming" - what whale is doing the swimming? Why does your rabbit have a whale? I suspect you may have missed the purpose of classes.

Comment: Classes aren't just a place to put functions; they define a type of object. The methods you define in a class are the definition of how that type of object behaves. Just from the names you've chosen, it looks like you may not have understood that. I don't see how a rabbit (or rabbits) could "carrots", for example.

Comment: I just renamed the info for simpler purposes.  One of the classes is a  fighter and the other is a weapon. The fighter has to use the weapon's attack method.

Comment: For future reference, that kind of renaming obscures the relationships between the objects. I don't think it even made the question any shorter.

Comment: can you code the scenario?

Comment: The answer below is pretty similar to the code I'm working with.
But, I can't use: 
def carrots(self, whale):
since whale is initialized in the __init__. That's why I'm still figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Fighter has-a weapon, thus can call Weapon's methods:

```
# weapon.py
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, name, dmg):
        self.name = name
        self.dmg  = dmg

    def attack(self, target):
        target.health -= self.dmg

# fighter.py
class Fighter:
    def __init__(self, name, weapon=None):
        self.name   = name
        self.weapon = weapon

    def attack(self, target):
        if self.weapon is None:
            # punch him
            target.health -= 2
        else:
            self.weapon.attack(target)
```